# Python search database function for title case insensitive

Tags: python, function, case-sensitive

I am making a function to search a mongo database with a python back end to search objects by their 'title' field. The search I have seems to be case sensitive, I cant figure out how to make this search without case sensitivity. Any Help welcome

```
@cross_origin(origin='*',headers=['Content-Type','Authorization'])
def search_by_title():
    
    title = request.args.get('title');
    
    pipeline = [ { "$match" : { "title" : title}},
                 { "$project" : {"title" : 1, "movie" : 1, "_id" : 1}}
                ]
    
    data_to_return = []
    for movie in movies.aggregate(pipeline):
        movie['_id'] = str(movie['_id'])
        
        data_to_return.append(movie)
    return make_response(jsonify(data_to_return), 200)
```

Comment: i am not sure how to fix it but try to play around with ```'title'.lower()``` or ```'title'.upper()```

Comment: You can either use a regular expression, or create a case insensitive index.  https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/schema-design-anti-pattern-case-insensitive-query-index/